# Swift - Got unrecognized selector error after extend from GADBannerView

Tags: swift, oop, inheritance, admob, extend

I want to build custom class that extends `GADBannerView` like other view but it doesn't work

```
class ListAd:GADBannerView {
    var controller: UIViewController?

    convenience init(hostView: UIView, controller: UIViewController) {
        self.init(frame: hostView.bounds)
        self.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.controller = controller
        hostView.addSubview(self)
    }

    func loadAd() {
        if APP.displayBannerAd {
            self.adUnitID = ADMOBIDS["banner"]
            self.rootViewController = controller
            self.load(GADRequest())
        }
    }
}
```

Then i initialize it

```
admobBanner = ListAd(hostView: self.view, controller: self)
admobBanner?.loadAd()
```

got error:

`[App.ListAd setAdUnitID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe7f9c04d60'`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `init(adSize: GADAdSize, origin: CGPoint)` or `init(adSize: GADAdSize)` instead of `self.init(frame:)`

Comment: What type is `admobBanner` defined? Do you have any warnings? I believe you are not receiving a `ListAd` instance upon calling `ListAd(hostView: self.view, controller: self)`, could you verify via debugger?

Comment: Obiviously it's `ListAd` type. `var admobBanner: ListAd?
` What do you expect? Everything works fine until i call `.loadAd()`. The object has been initialized, i can change it background color, but set adUnitID caused error

Comment: Hmm. yea, I'm wrong. You did receive a `ListAd` instance. I believe this an issue with the framework itself.